# Eclipse WindowBuilder Design Tab is Empty?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder, eclipse-photon

I'm new to the WindowBuilder tool of Eclipse (or any frontend dev), and I installed WindowBuilder, SWT to check it out.
When creating a new project, I go to:

**New > Others > WindowBuilder > SWT Designer > SWT/JFace Java Project**

When creating a new class, I go to:

**New > Others > WindowBuilder > Swing Designer > Application Window** or **JFrame**, or Under **> SWT Designer > SWT >Application Window**.

This generates an initial Main code and I have Source and Design Tabs below.
My problem is that when going to the design tab it's always empty as seen below:

[image]

The initial code in class has this:
[image]

And when executed creates this window:
[image]

I can't find any answers for this problem, and all tutorials I'm seeing have items inside the Design Tab where they can start exploring it.

Comment: In my case, it was a folder permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed** and then update(if not updated) both **WindowBuilder** and **WindowBuilder Nightly**

then Restart

to open file with **design** tab :
righclick on **.java** file **Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor**

finally click on **design tab** it may take few seconds to load

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall eclipse completely, the only thing you need to leave is the eclipse-workspaces folder, so your projects will remain saved.

To uninstall it completely you need to:

1. Delete the "eclipse" folder in "C:\Users\YourName".
2. Delete the desktop shortcut.
3. Delete the ".p2" folder in "C:\Users\YourName".

Reinstall eclipse from the official site.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try link:
https://youtu.be/LgOMN3US6Bk

I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and what i did was to update the windowbuilder to version: 1.9.2......

That solved the problem for me.

PS: Using Eclipse Photon